# How to excecute the object file in laravel with shell_exec or exec command?

Tags: php, laravel

I have an object file of CPP wants to execute with the shell_exec or exec commands.
But when I am passing the path for that Exe(object file) from my laravel project it shows NOT FOUND.

i am running the command like this.

```
` 
 $cmd ="./home/usr/Folder/ObejectFile $id $ip_Address 2>&1";
 $result = shell_exec($cmd); 
`
```

What am I doing wrong please help?

Comment: put your `exec` cmd as well

Answer (score 0):

the 2 possible causes:

1.

```
$cmd ="./home/usr/Folder/ObejectFile $id $ip_Address 2>&1";


$cmd ="/home/usr/Folder/ObejectFile $id $ip_Address 2>&1";
```

You want to write absolute path, but with an extra dot

2. You want to write a relative path, but the current path environment is not of this relative path.
   So you can first use the absolute path to make the code right, then change to a relative path.

Answer (score 0):

It's working now with this solution.

First, go to your folder with 'cd' to the exe/ObjectFile is placed in the folder. In the first Command.
`$first_command = "cd /path/to/folder/";`
Second, launch your exe/ObjectFile and pass your param also if you wish to. In the second command.
`$second_command = "./EXE|ObjectFile";`
`$final = "$first_command && $second_command 2>&1 ";`

Now run both commands in shell_exec($final)

It will hopefully.